# Twitter streaming issue using Nodejs "Twit"

Tags: node.js, twitter

I Just try to streaming tweets form twitter using nodejs with "Twit" (npm) my code is look as follows.

```
 stream = tweeter.stream('statuses/filter', { track: phrase, language: 'en' });
   var testTweetCount = 0;
    stream.on('tweet', function (data) { 
    var currentdate = new Date(); 
    var datetime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
            + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
            + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
            + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
            + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
            + currentdate.getSeconds();
        console.log("stream started Successfully with "+filterText+"-  "+datetime);      
        //socket.emit('gotTweetss'); 
        var tweetText = JSON.stringify(data.text);
        if(tweetText){
            var Created_at=JSON.stringify(data.created_at);
            var User=JSON.stringify(data.user.screen_name);
            tweetCollection.count({text:tweetText,user:User,Created_at:Created_at}, function(err, existdata){
            /*  console.log("existdata                           :                  " + existdata);*/
                if(existdata > 0){
                    console.log("duplicate data : " + JSON.stringify(existdata));
                } else{

                    var tText=filterText.split(',');
                    var chekTrue=false;

                    for(iix=0;iix<tText.length;iix++)
                    {

                        var twData=tweetText.toUpperCase();
                        var txzt=tText[iix].trim();
                        if(twData.indexOf(txzt.toUpperCase())>-1)
                            {
                                console.log('true');
                                chekTrue='true';break;
                            }

                    }
                    if(chekTrue=='true'){

                    tweetCollection.insert([{text:tweetText,user:User,Created_at:Created_at}], {w:1}, function (error) {
                        if (error){
                            console.log("Error Occurred " + error.message);
                        } else{
                            // Wait for a second before finishing up, to ensure we have written the item to disk
                            setTimeout(function() {

                                // Fetch the document
                                tweetCollection.findOne ({text:tweetText}, function (err, item) {
                                    assert.equal(null, err);
                                    if(item!=null)
                                    assert.equal(tweetText, item.text);

                                })
                            }, 1000);
                        }
                    });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        // socket.emit('gotTweet');
    });
    stream.on('error', function(error, code) {
        console.log("My error: " + error + ": " + code);
        /*if(code=="420")
        {
            io.sockets.emit('gotTweet');
        }*/
    });
    stream.on('delete', function(error, code) {
        console.log("My delete: : " + code);
    });
```

This is the code of start streaming area for getting stream for this am using 
'twit' NPM .Its show in console date and time for sync while streaming start,Its work fine. But some time tweets not getting properly,When i tweet in twitter this streaming not getting that tweets. Is there is any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this becuase of **language: 'en'**  in twitter stream

```
tweeter.stream('statuses/filter', { track: phrase, language: 'en' });
```

i just remove the language: 'en' in above code its work perfectly

```
tweeter.stream('statuses/filter', { track: phrase });
```